# SQLite timestamp format was not recognized

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite

I use ADO.NET Data Provider for SQLite for comunicating with sqlite db. I have a table with datetime field, which contains timestamp as a value.

When I try to get this value in my c# app I receive FormatException which says that "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

I use following code for getting variable:

```
command = new SQLiteCommand(cnn);
command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Library WHERE id=" + id.ToString() + ";";

reader = command.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
     IDataRecord record = (IDataRecord)reader;
     library.dateCreation = (UInt32)record[6];
}
// Call Close when done reading.
reader.Close();
```

dateCreation value is of type UInt32. How can I properly read this value? Maybe db has a wrong format? But I read that sqlite datetime field can contain timestamp value.

Comment: dateCreation is `UInt32` and you get `DateTime` exception ????

Comment: Yes, because as I wrote the database field has type datetime and I cannot change it, because it is external. The exception appears when i try to appeal to record[6]

Comment: Have you tried with `library.dateCreation = new DateTiem((long)record[6]);`?

Comment: I don't see that part of code, guess you should use `DateTime.Parse` for it

Comment: Don't inject parameters directly into queries. That's the source of by far the most common security attacks.

Comment: P.S.: It isn't an issue in this instance (`id.ToString()` cannot generate bad code, assuming `id` is an `int`). But it's a very bad habit, and there's no good reason to do it this way when a perfectly straightforward and simple alternative exists.

Comment: Using select * and hoping that the 6th Column might be what i want isn't on the ~secure~ side either.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't seem to match the error message you provided "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

Comment: DataBase provider agreed to change column type to int, so it is no problem any more. Thanks for all pieces of advice :)